# How can I activate the virtual environment from a python script and execute further instructions while inside of it?

Tags: python, bash, git-bash

Here's what I would like to do with my Python script:

1. Create virtual environment
2. Change directory into environment
3. Activate environment
4. Install django
5. Do other stuff...

I've managed to create the environment and change directory with the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

env_name = "env_new"
subprocess.run(["py", "-m", "venv", env_name])
chdir(env_name)
```

But activating the environment is a different story:

```
subprocess.run(["source", "./Scripts/activate"])  # Also tried with activate.bat
```

Result:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
subprocess.run([".", "./Scripts/activate"])  # Also tried with activate.bat
```

Result:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Just to clarify, I made sure I was in the correct directory by using print(os.getcwd()).

After this I'd then like to install django. I think it has to happen inside the same run() method like so:

```
subprocess.run([".", "./Scripts/activate", "&&", "pip", "install", "django"])  # Or something...
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you are on Windows, what is your shell? You can't usefully run `activate` in a subprocess because the result will disappear as soon as the subprocess exits. Also, without `shell=True`, you can't use `.` which is a Bash built-in. The usual solution is to `activate` before you start Python, but depending on what you want, you might also be able to run Python as a subprocess of Python; though this is often something you will want to avoid.

Comment: I'm using git bash. I can't activate it before hand because automating the creation of the environment as well the creation of files inside of the environment need to all happen within the script.

Comment: path to the activate script is `<venv-name>/bin/activate`. `source` is a bash-built in, not a command, and you need to execute it in the same process that will then execute more steps.

Comment: I know its `<venv-name>/bin/activate` but I've been testing just the activation from within the environment. "`source` is a bash-built in", what about `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of things wrong here. When you run a subprocess, the environment it creates disappears when the subprocess exits.

What you *can* do is wrap Python inside Python, something like

```py
import subprocess

env_name = "env_new"
subprocess.run(["py", "-m", "venv", env_name])

subprocess.run(["%s/bin/python" % env_name, "-c", """
    the rest of your Python code here
    """])
```

which of course is just a rather pointless complication, and better written as a shell script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

py -m venv env_new
. ./env_new/Scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python ./your_real_script_here.py
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure `env_name/bin/python` runs the activated Python on Windows, too. This should work on properly Unix-compatible platforms at least (though then `activate` is in `bin` too, not in `Scripts`).

Comment: Ok I suppose I forgot to add that I will be taking a command line argument when I run the script which will contain the name for the venv e.g. `django-setup env_django`. Is there a way to pass that information on to the shell script?

Comment: The first command-line argument to a shell script is `$1` (though you'll basically always want to quote it; `"$1"`).

Comment: I tried doing the above suggested (not the shell but the run method with python script as an argument), didn't get any errors however It's installing django globally. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like virtualenv/bin/python doesn't work in Windows then. You can still embed the shell script and run it all as an external process but again, the Python wrapper to do that is pretty uniquely useless.

Comment: Ok don't worry using the script worked. Thank you so much man, I was losing my mind. I was going to accept the answer but there is a little more I would like to add for anyone else who finds this. Is it possible for me to edit yours or make a new answer?

Comment: Feel free to edit, I'll revert the changes if I think it's too intrusive.

Comment: (Calling people "man" when you can't know their gender is rather risky.)

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full" can't edit. Also I use "man" with everyone lol, sorry if I offended.

Answer (score 1):

Original poster here. I just want to expand on **triplee**'s answer above by displaying the full code required to achieve my desired result.

**Python Script #1** - django-setup

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        subprocess.call(f"intermediary.sh {sys.argv[1]}", shell=True)
    else:
        print("No arguments given")
```

**Shell Script** - intermediary.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

py -m venv "env_$1"
cd "env_$1"
. ./Scripts/activate
pip install django
mkdir "$1"
cd "$1"
django-setup-2
```

**Python Script #2** - django-setup-2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.run(['django-admin', 'startproject', 'config', '.'])
print("More code here!")
```

Executing the command `django-setup blog` would achieve the following result:

```
env_blog/
    Scripts/
    Include/
    Lib/
    blog/
        config/
        manage.py
    pyvenv.cfg
```

Comment: The `shell=True` is useless here, and easily avoided. `subprocess.call(["intermediary.sh", sys.argv[1]])` also avoids the need for interpolating the argument into a string. Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) But as suggested before, the first level of Python wrapper is rather useless, too. (If you really want to keep it in Python, you can avoid the separate script file; just pass the entire script to `subprocess.call("""py -m venv "env_$1"; ...""", shell=True)`.)

Comment: (The current script has no Bash features; but if you need the script to be executed by Bash, you can add `executable='/bin/bash'` after `shell=True`.)

Answer (score -2):

1. For the creation of a virtual environment and using it, follow [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).
2. Alternatively, you may use [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) to create and manage your virtual environments.